# MongoDB missing some methods in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to Mongo, and seem to be having problems getting some basic things to work.

The annotated code is below.  The short of it is that `db.getCollectionNames` is undefined, and also `db.foo.find()` and also `db.foos.find()` **both** bomb out, even though there is a foo collection listed from the code that actually does work.

Is my mongo install missing some features or something?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongotest', function(err, db){
    try {
        db.collections(function(e, cols) {
            cols.forEach(function(col) {
                console.log(col.collectionName); //WORKS just fine
            });
        });
        console.log(typeof db.getCollectionNames); //undefined

        //db.foos.find(); //[TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined]
        //db.foo.find(); //[TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined]
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    } finally {
        setTimeout(function(){ db.close(); }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like you may be looking at the Mongo shell documentation or the old version of the API.  For instance, `getCollectionNames` is now `listCollections`. The 2.0 docs can be found [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api-docs/).

Comment: Yep - that works.  No need to explain the 2.0 docs - I can read them - but is db.<collection name>.insert or db.<collection name>.find no longer supported?

Comment: Looks like its `db.collection('<name>').find()`

Comment: Yep - @JohnnyHK - please post that as an answer so I can close this out.

Comment: Also `connect` returns a promise, so you can skip the callback / try catch, and use `then()` and `catch()` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may be looking at the Mongo shell documentation or an old version of the node.js native driver API.

In the current, [2.x version](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api-docs/) of the driver, `getCollectionNames` is replaced by [`listCollections`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#listCollections).

Regarding the `db.foo.find()` syntax, that's never been supported by the native driver as far as I know.  Instead, that would be:

```
db.collection('foo').find()
```

Comment: btw - from day 1 I *was* wondering how in the world db.foo could possibly work without Proxy really existing anywhere. If I had thought it through a bit more I may have avoided this question.  Thanks for the answer nonetheless :)