# db.listCollections() in ExpressJS returns an error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using ExpressJs + MongoDB and following code returns an error:

```
var db = monk(DB_URL);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.db = db;
  next();
});

app.get("/view_collections", function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, collections) {
        console.log(collections);
    }); 
});
```

The Error is:

```
TypeError: db.listCollections is not a function.
```

Other functions work perfectly. As an example, following code is working:

```
app.get('/testCollection', function (req, res) {
  var collection = req.db.get('testData');
  collection.find({}, {
    limit: 300,
    sort: {
      timestamp: -1
    }
  }, (e, entries) => {
    res.render('testView', {
      entries: entries
    });
  });
});
```

I tried both `db.getCollectionNames()` and `db.listCollections()` but both return the same error but in the shell `db.getCollectionNames()` works.

Can someone please tell me how to get a list of MonogoDB collections inside,

```
app.get("/view_collections", function (req, res) {
    //Here
});
```

Comment: ... and where are you defining req.db? I think you're missing that piece of code from your app.js?

Comment: Instead of assigning it to `db` again like `var db = req.db;` try directly `req.db.listCollections().toArray()` and see

Comment: It doesn't work either. It gives the error `TypeError: req.db.listCollections is not a function`

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214175/db-collectionnames-doesnt-work-in-node-js) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713737/mongodb-missing-some-methods-in-node)

Comment: Yes and yes. Both say that `db.listCollections()` should be used instead of `db.getCollectionNames()`. I've tried both.

Comment: Two questions... is your middleware hit? have you tried to place a console log to see i it is hit?... number 2... is req.db defined in your controller code? or is just that function?

Comment: 1). Where do you mean by middleware?
2). `req.db` is working in the given second example.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same error, a fix can be:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {


     const db = client.db(DBNAME)

     db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, items) {
        console.log(items)
            //and u can loop over items to fetch the names
            client.close();
    });
})
```

Comment: I think I found a solution but I can't remember how. If someone can confirm this answer I'll "Accept".

Comment: @kmchmk you might want to confirm the answer, since it has three upvotes now.(in context it might be helpful for others)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this clarifies more:

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb';

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => 

    const db = client.db('testdb');

    db.listCollections().toArray((err, collections) => {

       console.log(collections);

       client.close();
    });

});
```

Notice, that there is the same 'testdb' in two lines:

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb';

const db = client.db('testdb');
```

Works the same when 'testdb' in url is missed:

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
```

Comment: There a way to make the db const a global variable to use elsewhere in the code?